# Is it possible to extend this complexType in this wsdl?

Tags: xml, magento, wsdl

I do have an WDL looking like this, which I can not change:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions 
  xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
>
    <types>
        <schema 
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
          targetNamespace="urn:Magento"
        >
            <import 
              namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
              schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            />
            <complexType name="salesOrderEntity">
                <all>
                    <element 
                      name="increment_id" 
                      type="xsd:string" 
                      minOccurs="0"
                    />
                    <!-- lot more elements come here -->
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

And I would like to make an extension to the `complexType` `salesOrderEntity`, I saw that was possible in some WSDL ([I got the reference from here](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_03.aspx)).

Now I'm confused if it is possible and how to extend this specific `complexType`.

What I tried:

```xml
<complexType name="salesOrderCustomEntity">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="salesOrderEntity">
            <sequence>
                <element name="some_field" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

and

```xml
<complexType name="salesOrderCustomEntity">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="salesOrderEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="some_field" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </all>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

But, for both, I do get the `some_field` element but don't get all the elements of the `salesOrderEntity` `complexType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I did found it. The declaration states :

```xml
xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
```

So you have to extend the base complexType `typens:salesOrderEntity` and not just `salesOrderEntity`

```xml
<complexType name="salesOrderCustomEntity">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="typens:salesOrderEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="some_field" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </all>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```